# How to fix this exception java.lang.String cannot be cast to user defined type

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

guys, i am trying to iterate though a list of user defined objects but i get this error (java.lang.String cannot be cast to bg.fmi.master.thesis.model.TFilterType)  and i can not figure out why.

I my .xhtml i have:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="chkbox1"
                    value="#{requestBean.selectedBooleanFilterTypes}"
                    layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItems var="checkbox"
                        value="#{filterTypeBean.listBooleanFilterTypes()}"
                        itemLabel="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}" itemValue="#{checkbox}" />
                    <!-- required="true"
                         requiredMessage="check at least one checkbox"  -->

                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Part from the bean class:

```
private List<TFilterType> selectedBooleanFilterTypes;

public List<TFilterType> getSelectedBooleanFilterTypes() {
        return selectedBooleanFilterTypes;
    }

    public void setSelectedBooleanFilterTypes(
            List<TFilterType> selectedBooleanFilterTypes) {
        this.selectedBooleanFilterTypes = selectedBooleanFilterTypes;
    }
```

This is part from another method, but also in the bean class:

```
for (TFilterType type : selectedBooleanFilterTypes) {
            System.out.println("SelectedFilterTypes: "
                    + type.getFilterTypeName());
        }
```

During Debugging mode i can see that selectedBooleanFilterTypes has this value:

[TFilterType [filterTypeName=DJ, filterTypeDesc=DJ, isBooleanType=B, tRequestFilters=[]], TFilterType [filterTypeName=Украса, filterTypeDesc=Decoration, isBooleanType=B, tRequestFilters=[]]]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting an exception or a compiler error? (It sounds more like the latter.) Also, please identify the line that is causing the problem (including a stack trace if it's an exception).

Comment: This is the problem part:

    for (TFilterType type : selectedBooleanFilterTypes) {
                System.out.println("SelectedFilterTypes: "
                        + type.getFilterTypeName());
            }

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to bg.fmi.master.thesis.model.TFilterType
 at bg.fmi.master.thesis.beans.RequestBean.addRequest(RequestBean.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

Comment: This is line 80 in RequestBean: (TFilterType type : selectedBooleanFilterTypes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFilterType is a Java class. in this case you should use a faces converter for your type.
please try this sample

xhtml:

```xhtml
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="chkbox1" value="#{requestBean.selectedBooleanFilterTypes}"
                      layout="pageDirection" converter="filterTypeConverter">
    <f:selectItems var="checkbox" value="#{filterTypeBean.listBooleanFilterTypes()}"
                   itemLabel="#{checkbox.filterTypeName}" itemValue="#{checkbox}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

converter:

```java
@FacesConverter("filterTypeConverter")
public class TFilterTypeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        FilterTypeBean filterTypeBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{filterTypeBean}", FilterTypeBean.class);
        for (TFilterType type : filterTypeBean.listBooleanFilterTypes()) {
            if (type.getFilterTypeName().equals(value)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof TFilterType) {
            return ((TFilterType) value).getFilterTypeName();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```