# To save data to foreign key attribute in JPA using java persistence with dropdown element using EJB

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, ejb

Hi I want to save data form jsp file to derby database using jpa.But cannot save the data to the database.
In productorder page:
Where I need save value

```
public class ProductOrder implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
    private Customer customer;

    //getter 
    //setter
}
```

In EJB file:

```
public class OrderEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_Ebusiness_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public ProductOrder placeOrder(ProductOrder productOrder) {
        entityManager.persist(productOrder);
        return productOrder;
    }
}
```

In jsp(xhtml file) file:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{orderController.customer}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{orderController.customerList}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.name}" itemValue="#{c.id}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="Place a Order" action="#{orderController.placeOrder}"/>
</h:form>
```

My converter file:

```
public class CustomerConverter implements Converter{ 

    private transient EntityManager em; 

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) { 
        return em.find(Customer.class, new Integer(value));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) { 
        return ((Customer) o).getId().toString(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Any exception? error? You'll need the `referencedColumnName` attribute for the `customer` relationship btw. I guess your Customer is an Entity. You'll need a converter in your `<h:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: I tried to use controller but shows error like this: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to model.Customer 
    My converter file:  public class CustomerConverter implements Converter{
  
private transient EntityManager em;  

  
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    return em.find(Customer.class, new Integer(value));
    }

   
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
    return ((Customer) o).getId().toString(); 

    }
}

Comment: My converter file:

Comment: Can you update your post? It's hard to read your converter

Comment: Please check I have updated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Code errors

Your code contains some errors/missing point:

1. *missing optional referencedColumnName*: as stated in comment, the `JoinColumn` annotation is missing an attribute. The attribute is optional but I like to make sure what is referenced:

   ```
   public class ProductOrder implements Serializable {
       @ManyToOne
       // replace "id" with the appropriate column name
       @JoinColumn(name = "customerId", referencedColumnName = "id")
       private Customer customer;

       //getter 
       //setter
   }
   ```

   the `referencedColumnName` is the `FOREIGN KEY` parallel. The above annotation is reflecting the constraint:

   ```
   FOREIGN KEY (customerId) REFERENCES customer_table(id)
   ```
2. You're using *JSF, not JSP*. Please [refer to this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095397/4906586).
3. Your `selectOneMenu` is incorrect:

   ```
   <h:form>
       <h:selectOneMenu value="#{orderController.customer}" converter="customerConverter">
           <f:selectItems value="#{orderController.customerList}" var="c"
                          itemLabel="#{c.name}" itemValue="#{c}" />
       </h:selectOneMenu>
       <h:commandButton value="Place a Order" action="#{orderController.placeOrder}"/>
   </h:form>
   ```

   - *a converter tag* is missing. [BalusC offered an awesome explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850681/4906586).
   - your *itemValue* is supposed to refer to your customer object, not the customer id. Hence, it should be `itemValue="#{c}`.
4. You're converting the wrong value: your converter class converts `customerId <-> customer object` whereas in your selectOneMenu, you want to convert `customer name <-> customer object`
5. Your converter class may be missing the `@FacesConverter` annotation

### Solving

You'll need to solve each point one by one:

1. **Converter**: Choose what you want to display in your form, if you want to display the customer name, then your converter should look like:

   ```
   @FacesConverter
   @RequestScoped
   public class CustomerConverter implements Converter{ 

       // you would normally inject your EJB here. Please refer to BalusC's 
       // answer for more information
       // private transient EntityManager em;
       @EJB
       private CustomerService customerService;

       @Override
       public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
           return customerService.findByName(value);
       }

       @Override
       public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) { 
           return ((Customer) o).getName();
       }

   }
   ```

   in your customer service:

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService{

       @Override
       public Customer findByName(String name){
           // assuming you have a name query to fetch by name,
           // otherwise use em.createQuery(...)
           TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByName", Customer.class);
           query.setParameter("name", name);
           return query.getSingleResult();
       }
   }
   ```
2. when your converter is ready, adjust your `h:selectOneMenu` and `f:selectItems` accordingly

Comment: it shows what?? Please be clearer when you state your issues

Comment: I got this error when I submit the form  java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.Customer

Comment: Have you added the `converter` attribute in your `h:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: [The error states that your converter has an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303504/4906586). Maybe your converter class has an issue. Can you check that way?